# maximum recursion depth while using __setattr__ in python new style object?

Tags: python, class, object, getattr, setattr

I have the following code which comprises of a person class and a Manager class that delegates to a person class. I am using `new style object`(derived from `object`) and running python 2.7.
I geth maximum recursion depth which I am unable to understand. I know the problem happens when **setattr** is used (when I commented this out in manager class, I see it works fine).
why this recursion occurs and how to avoid it.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,name,job=None, pay=0):
        self.name=name
        self.job=job
        self.pay=pay

    def lastName(self):
        return self.name.split()[-1]

    def giveraise(self,percent):
        self.pay=int(self.pay*(1+percent))

    def __str__(self):
        return '[Person: %s, %s]' %(self.name, self.pay)


class Manager(object):
    def __init__(self,name,pay):
        self.person=Person(name,'mgr',pay)

    def giveraise(self, percent, bonus=0.10):
        self.person.giveraise(percent+bonus)

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        print "calling getattr"
        return getattr(self.person, attr)

    def __setattr__(self,attr, value):
        print "calling setattr"
        self.person__dict__["attr"]=value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.person)


if __name__=="__main__":

    sue = Person("sue Jones","dev",10000)
    sue.giveraise(0.10)
    print sue
    print sue.lastName()

    print "- -"*25

    tom = Manager("Tom mandy", 50000)
    tom.giveraise(.10)
    print tom
    print tom.lastName()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that in `Manager.__init__`, you call `__setattr__` to set the attribute `person`.  But in `__setattr__`, you assume that `self.person` has already been set and has a well defined `__dict__`.  In reality, it hasn't been set yet, so you end up calling `__getattr__` which calls itself forever trying to get `self.person`.

One possible fix here is to bypass the initial call to `__setattr__` in `Manager.__init__`:

```
class Manager(object):
    def __init__(self,name,pay):
        self.__dict__['person']=Person(name,'mgr',pay)
```

This should avoid the call to "`__getattr__('person')`" since `self.person` will already be set and normal attribute lookup will work<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>`__getattr__` is only called if normal attribute lookup fails</sup>

Comment: I changed __setattr__ to this: `def __setattr__(self,attr, value):
        print "calling setattr"
        return setattr(self.person,attr,value)` ,but still I get maximu recursion depth..why do I get this recursion depth problem..your solution works fine. but I want to understand why maximum recursion depth occurs

Comment: @user1988876 -- The problem is because at that point, `self.person` doesn't exist yet.  (It's never been set).  So, that forces a call to `__getattr__` which tries to get `self.person` which forces another call to `__getattr__` which tries to get `self.person` which ...

Comment: why does one call to __getattr__ forces another call to __getattr__, if the attribute is not found in the hierarchy, shouldnt it return `none` or something similar

Comment: @user1988876 -- because `__getattr__` has the line `self.person` in it.  That calls `__getattr__` (again!) if the attribute isn't found by the normal means.  There is no implicit returning of `None` done here.  Why would you expect there to be?

Answer (score 2):

The answer of mgilson is almost correct, however, in the `__setattr__` function of class manager a dot is missing in between `person__dict__`:

```
def __setattr__(self,attr, value):
        print "calling setattr"
        self.person__dict__["attr"]=value
```

When `__init__` tries to set self.person, the `__setattr__` queries for a non-existent attribute `person__dict__`, the Managers' `__getattr__` function gets called. It in turn queries for self.person, which does not exist at this stage, and at this stage you get a `__getattr__` recursion.